# Scaling a seaborn heatmap .png output file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6, heatmap, seaborn

I have a program that, in a nutshell, connects to a Cisco wireless controller and gathers data about the number of clients per access point.  It runs at 'x' intervals at 'y' time between intervals.

The program works fine.

*NOTE*  Both output files presented below show nine passes at 15 seconds between each pass.  All you really care about is that I have 9 columns (one per pass) and the rows are the AP's and their connected clients.

My issue is this:  when I run it against a small client (93 access points) the output looks exactly the way I want it to:

[image]

But when I run it against another client (1840 access points) the output looks like this:

[image]

Here is the relevant portion of my program:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(e, index=index, columns=cols)
df = df.transpose()

my_dpi = 96
sns.set(font_scale=2)
# plt.figure(figsize=(13, 91))
plt.figure(figsize=(2016 / my_dpi, 9120 / my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

sns.heatmap(df, cmap='RdYlGn_r', linewidths=0.5, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 20})

plt.savefig('d:\\python\\projects\\clients_per_ap\\ac.png')
plt.show()
```

I tried changing 9120 to 912000, but I get an error stating that the value has to be less than 2^16.  I tried 65535, but the program fails with a memory error.  I tried 54720 and that works -- 54720 produced the output you see here as the second image, but it is unusable.

How can I scale my output file for the client with 1840 AP's to look like the output file for the client wit 93 AP's?  Basically I would like the same (or very close) font and width, just 1840 rows long versus 93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried outputting the file in vector format? .PDF works well usually. Sure the text will look big when you zoom in, but that's probably your best bet for working with output that is too big to put into memory. Then you can just use any classic PDF to PNG conversion if you just need that for some reason.

Comment: I actually had to use an EPS formatted file to fully fix the issue, but your idea to use a vector formatted file versus a raster formatted file was correct.  I also had to tweak some of the heat map settings since the file is so much longer than it is wide.